# CheckedTextView drawing is not changing

Tags: android, user-interface

I already read some answers from Stackoverflow about this issue, but I still don't know why drawing of CheckedTextView isn't changing. Any ideas?

Code:

```
    ListLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout.list_items, null);
    CheckedTextView = (android.widget.CheckedTextView) ListLayout
        .findViewById(R.id.listChange);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable((R.drawable.action2));
    CheckedTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(image, null, null, null);
```

Layout:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listChange"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/action1"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip" />
```

Comment: Where's your variable of type `CheckedTextView`?For example ` CheckedTextView ctv = (android.widget.CheckedTextView) ListLayout
        .findViewById(R.id.listChange);` Here `ctv` is the variable.Then `ctv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(image, null, null, null);`Does it help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it didn't help.